# SQL Homework - "IN" Subquery

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007, subquery

yes this is a homework question, but I'm giving it honest effort and **I'm not asking you to do it for me, just point me in the right direction**! :)

So I have a set of questions concerning the SQL `IN` subquery, and while I understand what it does I'm having trouble applying it in these situations.

The first question:

> 1) Use the In subquery technique to list the customer number, customer name and  phone for customers who have paid either by visa or mc. Sort
>   by customer name.

This one I believe I got:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   tblCust.CustomerNum, CustomerName, Phone
FROM
   tblCust
INNER JOIN tblOrd ON
   tblCust.CustomerNum=tblOrd.CustomerNum
WHERE
   tblOrd.PayMethod IN ("visa", "mc")
ORDER BY CustomerName;
```

**But the next one just makes no sense to me:**

> 2) Use the In subquery technique to list from tblCust the customer number, customer  name and state for customers who have a state
>   description that begins with “co”.

Shouldn't I be using the LIKE operator for this instead of IN?
So far I have:

```
SELECT
   CustomerNum, CustomerName, StateProv
FROM
   tblCust
INNER JOIN tblState ON
   tblCust.StateProv = tblState.StateProv
WHERE 
   tblState.StateProvDesc IN
```

**And I don't know what to put after the IN, if I were using LIKE I would say**

> ...StateProvDesc LIKE "co%"

**and be done with it, but I don't think that's what my teacher wants.**
Finally, the third question:

> 3) Use the In subquery technique to list from tblCust the customer
>   name, country for  customers who have at least one order in the range
>   of $90,000-$120,000. Sort by  country then customer name.

Shouldn't between be used for a range of numbers?

Thanks for anything you guys can think of!

**using microsoft access by the way**

Comment: Your first answer is incorrect because you didn't use a subquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what the prof wants you to do is write a subquery within the IN clause. You can actually put a select statement within IN() like this:

```
SELECT
   CustomerNum, CustomerName, StateProv
FROM
   tblCust
WHERE StateProv IN(SELECT StateProv FROM tblState WHERE StateProvDesc LIKE 'co%')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the instructor wants you to change the query to use `... IN (SELECT ... FROM ...)` style instead of the inner join.

You can work on these queries from the back of the description, like this:

> ...a state description that begins with “co”.

```
-- Inner query
SELECT StateProv
FROM tblState
WHERE StateProvDesc LIKE `co%`
```

Now that you have this, you can compose the outer query:

> list from tblCust the customer number, customer name and state for customers who have...

```
SELECT
   CustomerNum, CustomerName, StateProv
FROM
   tblCust
WHERE tblCust.StateProv IN (
-- Your inner query goes here
)
```

Comment: Thank you! The step by step was definitely helpful!